# PING ERROR C# - Parameter name: hostName

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ping

I need help.. I checking for if user of PC connected to Internet..
It works for me.. and for many people.. But for someone no

and it's writing this into output_log.txt

ERROR:

```
ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.

Parameter name: hostName
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName (System.String hostName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.GetNonLoopbackIP () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendPrivileged (System.Net.IPAddress address, Int32 timeout, System.Byte[] buffer, System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send (System.Net.IPAddress address, Int32 timeout, System.Byte[] buffer, System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send (System.String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, System.Byte[] buffer, System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send (System.String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, System.Byte[] buffer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send (System.String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send (System.String hostNameOrAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping:Send (string)

  at Internet.Connection.Check () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at MyGame.Load.Loader.StartLoading () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Loader+<Start>c__IteratorA.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

(Filename:  Line: -1)
```

Code:

```
namespace Internet
{
    using System;
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Connection
    {
        public static void Check()
        {
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
            if (ping.Send("89.203.249.74").Status != IPStatus.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log("NO INTERNET CONNECTION");
                Application.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So Please help

Comment: For that someone, what their platform?

Comment: Mb. Check .NET version

Comment: maybe fixed.. using other script